# How to revert back my GitHub commit to the previous one?

Tags: git, github

I have a private GitHub repository.
I only push to the main branch and I'm the only person with access to the repository.

[image]

I would like to bring back things as they were 4 days ago (to the commit on Dec 5, 2020) and that last commit (5 hours ago) to disappear.

I used the following commands when I pushed to git.

```
   git add notes.org
   git commit -m "Sync"
   git push
```

I would be grateful for any suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all traces of the new commit, you need to reset your branch back to an earlier state (commit) that doesn't include that. If you're just removing the first most recent commit, you could do

```
# switch to your branch
git switch your-branch

# reset your branch hard to point to the (1) most recent commit
git reset --hard your-branch~1

# push the new state of your branch to the server forcefully
git push your-remote your-branch --force-with-lease
```

Comment: Yes, whatever it is in your case. By default, the remote is called `origin` and the branch is `main` or `master`. Use whatever it is in your case. If you're unsure what it is, you could use the `git remote` and `git branch` command to list the remotes and branches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following two commands to remove the last commit on your end, and force github to match yours.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git push origin -f
```

If the second command does not work, try

```
git push --force origin main
```

Comment: If your main branch is not called "main", replace it with the name, i.e., `git push --force origin master` if it's called "master".